# sideloading in windows 8.1 with bing

Tags: windows-8.1, sideloading

Can Microsoft enterprise sideloading license be an add-on license to Windows 8.1 with Bing?

I'm trying to manage a bunch of windows tablets via air-watch. The tablets are preinstalled with Windows 8.1 with Bing system. In air-watch, I need to a enterprise sideloading key if I want to push some windows apps to windows tablets with publishing it to windows app store. What should I do in this situation? upgrades the tablets? or purchase a enterprise sideloading key? Where to purchase?

Thanks.